# Missing wp-content file in sources when inspecting my website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

ok so i'm creating my own theme for a website usually this works just fine but for some reason my style sheet isn't working and the wp-content file in sources when inspecting my website is missing. The only files I can see are what are in wp-includes and my index. This only happens when I create my own theme if I active one of the default ones its fine. I've noticed this only happens when I add my header and footer php files to the ftp. Here's my code

header:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UFT-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    header
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

footer:

```
<div>
    footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
/*
    Theme Name: Lester G
    Author: Fyber ltd
*/

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

that's all my content can you see anything wrong?

Comment: Where are you enqueuing the stylesheet?

Comment: I thought the style.css one is added automatically. Am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I know you have to add it too. I always enqueue my default style.css using wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

Comment: you have to include you stylsheet by yourself, it's not automatic

Comment: @NeilK I'll give it a try but I was just looking at my other websites and I haven't done this. It's very confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enqueue the default style.css in the functions.php using `wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() )`;